# Maya: after bake into control rig, IK will auto reset when I change another IK

Tags: maya

Arter setting one IK on my control rig, when I start to set the next IK, the previous one resets to its prior state.

Here's an example of my problem:

[image]

How can I keep the previous IK from resetting?

Answer (score 1):

update 18-7-11
finally I find the best way is use maya "Auto Key"
[image]

update 18-7-11
I find my old solution is not good, it cause I cannot select time slider, so I should use following way to instead:

I should following way to fix it:

```
scripJob -attributeChange
```

when attributeChange, auto save key

update 18-7-10
following is my code to fix this bug, invoke my code `fix` meth in maya script editor > python

```
import maya.cmds as mc
from kernel import *
def fix():
    mc.scriptJob(event=["timeChanged", reselect_character])


last_key_frame = None


def reselect_character():
    """
    I cannot find maya python get cur character func, so I default use ro_character character set
    :return:
    """
    global last_key_frame
    cur_key_frame = mc.currentTime(query=True)
    if cur_key_frame == last_key_frame:
        last_key_frame = cur_key_frame
        return
    character_set_name = "ro_character"

    if (not mc.objExists(character_set_name)):
        mel("character -name " + character_set_name + " -excludeVisibility -excludeScale;")
    mel("setCurrentCharacters( { \"" + character_set_name + "\" } );")
```

update 18-7-9
I find this bug occurs when time slider click(time change)

when i create character set, and reselect current same character set("No Character Set" doesn't work), the ik will not be reset, the bug wil fix

how to:

make maya script

update -timeChange cannot when click time slider, use scriptJob > timeChanged Cond; maya mel: scriptJob -timeChange, it can detect time slider change,

when time slider change, reselect current character set

if not character set, create character set in maya script

**following soluiton doesn't work, see above solution**

I guess it's bug in maya 2017, when i preferences > settings > time slider > key ticks > select "channel box" and click save

it fixed, and then i select "key ticks" > "active", it still fixed

I guess maybe my prefs interrupt and when i click Preferences > "save", the prefs will return to normal